# Cannot call xml.dom.minidom.parse inside class

Tags: python, xml, minidom

I am unable to call `xml.dom.minidom.parse()` within my class

As a sheer example,

```
class XmlReader:
   def __init__(self, xml):
      self.xml = xml 
      DOMTree = xml.dom.minidom.parse("test.xml")

xmlReader = XmlReader("test.xml")
```

Throws

```
File "handler2.py", line 10, in ?
    xmlReader = XmlReader("test.xml")
  File "handler2.py", line 8, in __init__
    DOMTree = xml.dom.minidom.parse("test.xml")
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'dom'
```

However outside I am able to call xml.dom.minidom.parse just fine.

What do I need to change in order to be able to call the function within my XmlReader class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside your constructor, `xml` refers to the **parameter** `xml` instead of the **module** `xml`. This is called *shadowing*. Choose a different name for one of them.

```
import xml as xml_module
```

or

```
from xml.dom import minidom
```

or

```
def __init__(self, xml_data):
```

Comment: Oh. Super good to know. I'm not as familiar with languages where everything is an object so this is great to know. Thank you for your help!